# How to suppress __pycache__ creation with Conda in Windows

Tags: python, windows, caching, environment-variables, anaconda

**Problem:** I have conda 4.2.13 installed on Windows 7 and I would like suppress the creation of the `__pycache__` folder every time I import some python (3) module created by me. In order to do so I read on different posts in the internet that the solution consists in setting the environment variable `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1`.

**Question:** Supposing this is the right solution, can you tell me what steps I have to do in practice to reach my goal? Is there any other alternative? if yes what should I do instead?

Comment: In older Python versions `sys.dont_write_bytecode = True` used to do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible workaround to delete the folder every time is created

```
# Place this lines somewhere in the code
import shutil
shutil.rmtree('./__pycache__',ignore_errors=True)
```

The folder is still generated but it's immediately removed.